# Aggregating data with query for ASP MVC 3 controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have three tables:

> PackageName: PackageNameID,PackageName
>
> Food: FoodID,Food
>
> PackageContent: PackageContentID, PackageNameID, FoodID, Qty

What I'm trying to do is display something like this:

> - PackageName (Food=Qty, Food=Qty) Edit | Details | Delete
> - A (Onions=4,Peppers=3)   Edit | Details | Delete
> - B (Rolls=2,Onions=2) Edit | Details | Delete

Here is my view model:

```
public class PackageViewModel
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<FoodItem> FoodItems { set;get;}
  public PackageViewModel()
  {
     FoodItems=new List<FoodItem>();
  }
}
public class FoodItem
{
  public string FoodName { set;get;}
  public int Quantity { set;get;}
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model List<PackageViewModel>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
   <td>@item.Name</td>
   <td>
       foreach(var food in item.FoodItems)
       {
         @food.FoodName - @food.Quantity
       }
   </td>
   <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit",new {@id=item.ID})
   </td>
  </tr>
}
```

This is the query I am using in my controller:

```
List< PackageViewModel > listVM=new List< PackageViewModel >();

listVM =

        from pn in db.PackageNames
        from pc in db.PackageContents
            .Where(p => p.PackageNameID == pn.PackageNameID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from f in db.Foods
            .Where(f => f.FoodID == pc.FoodID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new PackageViewModel { PackageNameID = pc.PackageNameID, PackageName = pn.PackageName, FoodItems = f.Food.ToList() };

    return View(listVM);
```

But, I get the following error: 
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'**

Further, the select line isn't right anyway....I need to assign both the name of the food ("Food" from the "Food" table) and the quantity of this food item ("Qty" from the "PackageContent" table) to the "FoodItems" list in the model. How do I do this?

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the type parameters of the conflicting `List` types, but I'm pretty sure it's got to do with the part

```
FoodItems = f.Food.ToList()
```

`FoodItems` is a `List<FoodItem>`, `FoodItem` being a auxiliary class in your view model, while `f.Food` is a collection of `Food` entity objects.

Something like this probably works:

```
FoodItems = f.Food.Select(fi => new FoodItem 
                                { 
                                   FoodName = fi.Name,
                                   Quantity = fi.Quantity
                                })
```

Although I have to guess what your entity classes look like.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That got rid of the error, but now I have two new ones:  

Error 1 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
  
Error 2 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Quantity' and no extension method 'Quantity' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
  
**Thank you**

Comment: Well, your objects probably have other properties, but as I said, I have to guess a bit, because I can't see your class model.